# UEFI not recognising EFI partition: no booting options

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I messed up the EFI partition and now when I boot my computer it opens the BIOS interface without any boot option, as if my disk has been erased.
However using a live USB (which is correctly recognised and booted) and using grub command line I've been able to boot my principal OS (Ubuntu).
However I don't know how to fix this problem.
I've tried running grub-install /dev/sda but it didn't changed anything.

The EFI partition seems completely fine: it has the correct flag (esp, boot) and there are all the correct files inside.

```
tree /boot/efi/
└── EFI
    ├── Boot
    │   └── bootx64.efi
    ├── Microsoft
    │   ├── Boot
    │   .....
    └── ubuntu
        ├── fbx64.efi
        ├── fw
        ├── fwupx64.efi
        ├── grub.cfg
        ├── grubx64.efi
        ├── mmx64.efi
        └── shimx64.efi
```

What I should check? What I'm missing?

This is my partition table:

```
parted /dev/sda print
Model: ATA Crucial_CT525MX3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 525GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  1612MB  1611MB  fat32        EFI System Partition          boot, esp
 2      1612MB  87.9GB  86.3GB  ext4         Ubuntu
 3      87.9GB  281GB   193GB   ext4         Home
 5      290GB   290GB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 6      290GB   405GB   115GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 8      405GB   500GB   94.4GB  ntfs         Data                          msftdata
 9      500GB   525GB   25.3GB  ext4         Backup OS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem simply formatting the partition (FAT32 with boot flag as obviously), mounting it and running `grub-install`. Then I had only to update the UUID in `/etc/fstab`. For Windows I had to use a USB with the installer and use the utility `bcdboot` to rewrite the EFI.

Answer (score 5):

I had to rename `/EFI/my-custom-label/grubx64.efi` to `/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` for my Asus UEFI BIOS to start recognizing it.

- Source 1: I flashed an SD card with Arch Linux ISO, and Asus UEFI recognized it. I inspected the EFI partition and the main Arch bootloader is `/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi`.
- Source 2: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/bios-does-not-recognize-efi-system-as-boot-partition/24025/19

This problem occurred on Asus Maximus VII Impact (Z97 chipset). My friend has a similar issue on an Z87-based Asus motherboard.

Answer (score 3):

There is another issue that can cause this, which I have recently hit.

To detect this issue, boot from a Linux live and run gdisk /dev/sd[whatever-your-disk-is] , usually /dev/sda or /dev/sdb or /dev/sdc .

Give the p command to ensure you see the right list of partitions (if not, this might not be your disk).

Then give the v command. And it might respond with this:

```
Warning: The 0xEE protective partition in the MBR is marked as active. This is
technically a violation of the GPT specification, and can cause some EFIs to
ignore the disk, but it is required to boot from a GPT disk on some BIOS-based
computers. You can clear this flag by creating a fresh protective MBR using
the 'n' option on the experts' menu.
```

If this is the response, use the commands: e, n, w. Then reboot and you might have your EFI back!

Comment: This fixed my issue! One note: For my installation, to get to the expert menu in gdisk I needed to press 'x' instead of 'e'.

FWIW, I was following these instructions when I encountered this issue: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/bios-uefi. My disk was already using GPT, but I wanted to switch from BIOS to UEFI boot.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is your EFI system variables aren't being set to point to the right bootloader. The program you want to check this is `efibootmgr`. This will show you all of the boot entries stored in NVRAM.

In theory, `grub-install` should handle this, but you may not be passing the right options. This sample command SHOULD work:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=ESP_MOUNT_PATH --bootloader-id=grub
```

Change `ESP_MOUNT_PATH` to the path of your EFI dir.

If this doesn't work, you can try using `efibootmgr` directly:

```
efibootmgr --create --disk /dev/sda --part 1 --loader /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi --label "GRUB"
```

I think on some systems you may have to use `/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi`. So try something like this and see what works.

Comment: I've tried both the commands: they worked correctly (the second had created a new boot entry which i can display trough efibootmgr ) however when I turn on my pc I get to the BIOS screen with no boot options

Comment: Couple things: 

* it LOOKS ok, but can you print /dev/sda's partition table in gdisk, to make sure that has the correct partition type: EF00?

* Also, check in your BIOS settings for things like 'Legacy Boot', or CSM (Compatability Support Module) - try disabling those, to force the BIOS to ONLY go for GPT/EFI boot, and totally skip its MBR booting logic - see if that helps.

* Do you have any other hard drives, that may have another EFI system partition on them?

Answer (score 0):

I also had grub not showing all partitions when booting with EFI, adding the parameter `--modules="part_gpt part_msdos"` to `grub-install` allowed it to show all partitions with `ls` and `ls -l`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to run `gdisk` to write a GPT instead of an MBR to the disk.

Comment: It does appear that the OP has: "Partition Table: gpt"

Comment: You're right, I missed that in the output of `parted`. But maybe I'll leave that here, because for me that solved the issue when I had the very same symptoms.